# c#,mvc,backbone, timer

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to create multiple timers. Any tutorials which can help me. The most difficult part is the html part and how to link my files a sample project would do me good.

```
Html5.Views.Timer = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: 'div#timer',

  initialize: function() {
    timer = this.model;
    this.render();
  },

  events: {
    "clicked div#add_time": "update_timer"
  }

  render: function() {
    $(this.el).append(HandlebarsTemplates['timer'](timer);
    this.start_timer();
  },

  start_timer: function() {
    clearTimeout(this.main_timer); 
    this.main_timer = setTimeout(function()  {
      if (this.countDownInstance) {
        this.countDownInstance.clearRewriteCounter();
      }
      this.countDownInstance = new countDown(timed.length, 'main_timer');
    }, timed_length*1000);
  },

  update_timer: function() {
    timed.length = timed.length+30
    this.start_timer();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a typo or you use `timed_length` or you use `timed.length`.. Also I think `timed.length` should returns an error at least there is a variable called `timed` in a global scope.

Also the line `timer = this.model;` is declaring a variable `timer` in a global scope.

Also the calls to `timed_length` maybe you want to change them to `this.timed_length`.

Summarizing.. I think there are **a bunch of typos** here.

Comment: now this becomes complicated for a graduate developer like me is it fair that you can rewrite the above code for me?

Comment: Sorry @ak47 you should make an effort.

Comment: timed_length : function() { if (this.seconds > 0 || this.minutes > 0) {
        this.seconds = this.seconds - 1;
        if (this.seconds == 0) {
            this.minutes = this.minutes - 1;
            this.seconds = 59;
        } else {
            this.seconds = this.seconds - 1;
        }
    }
but it is not working still :(

Comment: i have given up on doing this countdown :(